# XML attribute space separated character list cannot contain both single and double quotes

Tags: xml, validation, xml-attribute

I am using deltaxml (www.deltaxml.com) to compare 2 XML files.
I need to modify define-punctuation.xsl (XSLT) file.

To change the characters that should be treated as punctuation, the deltaxml:punctuation attribute should be included in an element with the punctuation characters in a space separated list.

This is what I am trying to use for select attribute:

<xsl:param name="punctuation" select=". , ; : ! ( ) [ ] { } - / & @ \ # % ? ' " ‘ ’ “ ” * $ € £ ¥ "/>

I get an error in Visual Studio 2010 XML editor:
Expected end of the expression, found ','.   .  -->,<--  ; : ! ( ) [ ] { } - / & @ \ # %...

I think the problematic punctuation characters are ' and "

This works: select=""'" for single quote, as well as
select="'&quot ;'"  (there is no space between 't' and ';')
, but I cannot have a single and double quote combined in select attribute.

So how to have them in select attribute?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<this temp=".,;:!()[]{}-/&amp;@\#%?'&quot;‘’“”*$€£¥"/>
```

Works fine at my Visual Studio 2010.

Also works fine :

```
<xsl:param name="test">
    .&#x20;,&#x20;;&#x20;:&#x20;!&#x20;(&#x20;)&#x20;[&#x20;]&#x20;{&#x20;}&#x20;-&#x20;/&#x20;&amp;&#x20;@&#x20;\&#x20;#&#x20;%&#x20;?&#x20;&apos;&#x20;&quot;&#x20;‘&#x20;’&#x20;“&#x20;”&#x20;*&#x20;$&#x20;€&#x20;£&#x20;¥
</xsl:param>
```

Btw .xsl is also .xml. Select however forbids certain characters.

Comment: This is not a regular XML. It is part of XSLT. this element is not part of xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" namespace. You can try creating xsl:param element and add space delimited characters in select attribute. It simple won't work for me. Remember I want to include apostrophe rendered as ' and quote symbol "